# How to change function pointers in glib's GMemVTable structure

Tags: memory-management, function-pointers, glib

I'm using glib on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I am using the memory monitor of glib (function g_mem_profile() printing mem usage and how much memory hasn't been freed).
g_mem_profile shows that ~3k aren't freed. One of the blocks which is allocated but not freed has 252 bytes size.

I was thinking of something like: I replace the malloc function in GMemVTable to

```
gpointer test_malloc (gsize nBytes)
{
    if (nBytes == 252)
        printf ("Gotcha!\n");
    return malloc (nBytes);
}
```

so that I can go into the debugger, set a breakpoint in the printf line and then check the call stack who is allocating those 252 bytes.
Here is the code I use to replace the corresponding GMemVTable member:

```
static gpointer test_malloc (gsize nBytes)
{
    if (nBytes == 252)
        printf ("Bin hier!!!! %" G_GSIZE_FORMAT, nBytes);
    return malloc (nBytes);
}

static void memory_helper ()
{
    /*kpodcast_mem_vtable.malloc = glib_mem_profiler_table->malloc;*/
    kpodcast_mem_vtable.malloc = test_malloc;
    kpodcast_mem_vtable.realloc = glib_mem_profiler_table->realloc;
    kpodcast_mem_vtable.free = glib_mem_profiler_table->free;
    kpodcast_mem_vtable.calloc = glib_mem_profiler_table->calloc;
    kpodcast_mem_vtable.try_malloc = glib_mem_profiler_table->try_malloc;
    kpodcast_mem_vtable.try_realloc = glib_mem_profiler_table->try_realloc;

}
```

When I use this code the program crashes:

```
*** Error in `./kpodcast': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000024de530 ***
```

When I uncomment the first line so that glib_mem_profiler_table->malloc is used it doesn't crash.
What am I doing wrong? It must have to do with the way I'm using the function pointers.

Many thanks
Kai

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're seeing this error message but there may be another way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

It turns out GLib has a built-in mechanism for trapping memory allocations of a specific size, enabled when the library is built with debugging features enabled (so you may need to [download the GLib source](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/glib/) then build and install your own local copy of the library). From [`docs/debugging.txt`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/docs/debugging.txt) within the GLib distribution:

```
Some code portions contain trap variables that can be set during
debugging time if G_ENABLE_DEBUG has been defined upon compilation
(use the --enable-debug=yes option to configure for this, macros.txt
covers more details).
Such traps lead to immediate code halts to examine the current
program state and backtrace.
Currently, the following trap variables exist:

...

static volatile gulong g_trap_malloc_size;
        If set to a size > 0, g_free(), g_realloc() and g_malloc()
        respectively, will be intercepted if the size matches the
        size of the corresponding memory block to free/reallocate/allocate.
        This will only work with g_mem_set_vtable (glib_mem_profiler_table)
        upon startup though, because memory profiling is required to match
        on the memory block sizes.
```

The `static volatile` declaration and breakpoint-triggering behaviour of the implementation makes me think you're meant to load your app inside a debugger, then stuff a value into this variable and let the program run. When an allocation of the specified size is made the library will trap back into the debugger, allowing you to examine the backtrace and see where the allocation was made within your code.